# Check box not ticking on HTML WebBrowser VB.Net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to automatically tick a text box on a vb.net web browser when the page loads the HTML of the check box is as follows

```
<input checked="checked" class="checkbox" id="order_terms" name="order[terms]" type="checkbox" value="1" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

This is what I am trying to use to tick the box but it doesn't seem to work

```
WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("order_terms").SetAttribute("checked", "True")
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: PLZ can someone help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you seek by doing the following:

```
Dim Document As mshtml.HTMLDocument = DirectCast(WebBrowser2.Document, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
Dim Input As mshtml.HTMLInputElement = TryCast(Document.getElementById("order_terms"), mshtml.HTMLInputElement)

If Input IsNot Nothing Then
    input.checked = false 'Uncheck the checkbox
End If
```

(You will need to add a reference to microsoft.mshtml)

Comment: Sorry but element.checked is not recognized in VB.Net 2012

Comment: If you could help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I edited the answer.
Take a look. 
I believe it will work for you now. 
As for my initial answer, I think you would have needed (probably) to set LateBinding to "none" in error type (This is vs2015 default). However, with this edited answer, you can use it as it is, provided you add mshtml reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added a reference to microsoft.mshtml and added the code to my program but it still doesn't check the checkbox I have no idea what to do here

Comment: Well, in my example, I unchecked the checkbox (Checked=False). You did modify that to True, right ?

Also, can you confirm me that Input isnot nothing ?
If you try to execute the code before the Load_Completed (WPF webbrowser) event is called, Input will be nothing and therefore, Input,checked condition will never be executed.